# Escaping or replacing a value in XSLT 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, replace, escaping, double-quotes

I'm pretty new to XSLT. My problem is that some of the values contain double quotes which seems to cause AJAX to fail when I get it from my web page. I've already looked at some exaples and people with similar issues with no luck adapting it to this.

What I'm trying to do in the code below is try to replace any occurances of double quotes found in the value of "artist" with single quotes. I did also try it using \ (escape character) without any luck. Does anyone know how I can get this to work?

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="text" indent="no" encoding="UTF-8"/>

 <xsl:template match="/icestats">

parseMusic(
{
  <xsl:for-each select="source">"<xsl:value-of select="@mount"/>":{
  "server_name":"<xsl:value-of select="server_name"/>",
  "listeners":"<xsl:value-of select="listeners"/>",
  "description":"<xsl:value-of select="server_description" />",
  "title":"<xsl:if test="artist"><xsl:variable name="s1" select="artist"/><xsl:value-of select="replace($s1,'"',"'")"/> - </xsl:if><xsl:value-of select="title" />",
  "genre":"<xsl:value-of select="genre" />",
  "bitrate":"<xsl:value-of select="bitrate" />",
  "url":"<xsl:value-of select="server_url" />"}<xsl:if test="position() != last()"><xsl:text>,
  </xsl:text></xsl:if></xsl:for-each>
});
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Example input for "artist" field. Don't worry about the title field, as I just have it as an empty string.

```
Ocean View ["Sonic, You Can Do Anything" from Sonic CD & "Super Sonic Racing" from Sonic R] [~~] Sonic & All-Stars Racing: Transformed - Original Sound Version [~~] [''Opening'' from Panzer Dragoon] Richard Jacques
```

Comment: Could you provide us with a (minimal) example of input for testing?

Comment: Just made an edit wht an example.

Comment: I am afraid that's not a good example, because it contains an unescaped `&` character.

Answer (score 1):

**XSLT 2.0 only**

Try:

```
<xsl:value-of select="translate(artist, '&quot;', '''')"/>
```

With the following **input example**:

```
<artist>I'm "quoted". We're all "quoted".</artist>
```

the **result** should be:

```
I'm 'quoted'. We're all 'quoted'.
```

Comment: The section in question looks like this now after trying out your suggestion. I'm getting parsing erros though. Maybe I'm missing something?

    "title":"<xsl:if test="artist"><xsl:value-of select="translate(artist, '&quot;', '''')"/> - </xsl:if><xsl:value-of select="title" />"

Comment: I am afraid I don't follow. Posting code in comments is not q good idea - edit your question instead and add the new developments there. BTW, I don't see why you need the xsl:if; if the artist is  not there, then it has no value and nothing will be output anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It's always easier to talk about a real, actual XML input example:

**XML Input**

What you suggest as the content of the `artist` element is in fact *malformed* XML, because there are unescaped "&" characters in it. As you can see, they are escaped to `&amp;` below. If you cannot hand to XSLT XML where "&"s are escaped, no transformation can take place at all.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<icestats>
    <source mount="1">
        <server_name>John</server_name>
        <listeners>Broderick</listeners>
        <server_description>SRV39474</server_description>
        <server_url>www.url.com</server_url>
        <artist>Ocean View ["Sonic, You Can Do Anything" from Sonic CD &amp; "Super Sonic Racing" from Sonic R] [~~] Sonic &amp; All-Stars Racing: Transformed - Original Sound Version [~~] [''Opening'' from Panzer Dragoon] Richard Jacques</artist>
        <title>Funny Tune</title>
        <genre>Rock</genre>
        <bitrate>123456</bitrate>
    </source>
</icestats>
```

**XSLT Stylesheet**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="text" indent="no" encoding="UTF-8"/>

 <xsl:template match="/icestats">

parseMusic(
{
  <xsl:for-each select="source">"<xsl:value-of select="@mount"/>":{
  "server_name":"<xsl:value-of select="server_name"/>",
  "listeners":"<xsl:value-of select="listeners"/>",
  "description":"<xsl:value-of select="server_description" />",
  "title":"<xsl:if test="artist"><xsl:variable name="s1" select="artist"/><xsl:value-of select="replace($s1,'&quot;','&apos;&apos;')"/> - </xsl:if><xsl:value-of select="title" />",
  "genre":"<xsl:value-of select="genre" />",
  "bitrate":"<xsl:value-of select="bitrate" />",
  "url":"<xsl:value-of select="server_url" />"}<xsl:if test="position() != last()"><xsl:text>,
  </xsl:text></xsl:if></xsl:for-each>
});
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**JSON Output**

Caveat: Outputting JSON is not something XSLT is good at. You have no guarantee whatsoever that the result produced is also valid JSON.

```
parseMusic(
{
  "1":{
  "server_name":"John",
  "listeners":"Broderick",
  "description":"SRV39474",
  "title":"Ocean View ['Sonic, You Can Do Anything' from Sonic CD & 'Super Sonic Racing' from Sonic R] [~~] Sonic & All-Stars Racing: Transformed - Original Sound Version [~~] [''Opening'' from Panzer Dragoon] Richard Jacques - Funny Tune",
  "genre":"Rock",
  "bitrate":"123456",
  "url":"www.url.com"}
});
```

**EDIT: Another Stylesheet, this time XSLT 1.0**

I am borrowing code from an answer by Dimitre Novatchev [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9371527/1987598).

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="text" indent="no" encoding="UTF-8"/>

 <xsl:template match="/icestats">

parseMusic(
{
    <xsl:for-each select="source">"<xsl:value-of select="@mount"/>":{
    "server_name":"<xsl:value-of select="server_name"/>",
    "listeners":"<xsl:value-of select="listeners"/>",
    "description":"<xsl:value-of select="server_description" />",
    "title":"<xsl:if test="artist"><xsl:variable name="s1" select="artist"/><xsl:call-template name="escapeQuote"><xsl:with-param name="pText" select="$s1"/></xsl:call-template> - </xsl:if><xsl:value-of select="title" />",
    "genre":"<xsl:value-of select="genre" />",
    "bitrate":"<xsl:value-of select="bitrate" />",
    "url":"<xsl:value-of select="server_url" />"}<xsl:if test="position() != last()"><xsl:text>,
      </xsl:text></xsl:if></xsl:for-each>
});
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="escapeQuote">
      <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>

      <xsl:if test="string-length($pText) >0">
       <xsl:value-of select=
        "substring-before(concat($pText, '&quot;'), '&quot;')"/>

       <xsl:if test="contains($pText, '&quot;')">
        <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>

        <xsl:call-template name="escapeQuote">
          <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
          "substring-after($pText, '&quot;')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
       </xsl:if>
      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is exactly the same.

---

**Yet another stylesheet**

Your original XSLT code outputs text inside `xsl:template`. But this relies on the indentation and returns in your XSLT stylesheet. It would be wiser to put any text inside `<xsl:text/>`elements to control whitespace output. Also, the code is much easier to read.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" method="text" indent="no" encoding="UTF-8"/>

    <xsl:template match="/icestats">

        <xsl:text>parseMusic(&#10;{&#10;</xsl:text>

        <xsl:for-each select="source">
            <xsl:text>&#09;"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@mount"/>
            <xsl:text>":{&#10;&#09;"server_name":"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="server_name"/>
            <xsl:text>",&#10;&#09;"listeners":"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="listeners"/>
            <xsl:text>",&#10;&#09;"description":"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="server_description" />
            <xsl:text>",&#10;&#09;"title":"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:if test="artist">
                <xsl:variable name="s1" select="artist"/>
                <xsl:call-template name="escapeQuote">
                    <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="$s1"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
                <xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:value-of select="title" />
            <xsl:text>",&#10;&#09;"genre":"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="genre" />
            <xsl:text>",&#10;&#09;"bitrate":"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="bitrate" />
            <xsl:text>",&#10;&#09;"url":"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="server_url" />
            <xsl:text>"}</xsl:text>
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:text>&#10;});</xsl:text>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="escapeQuote">
      <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>

      <xsl:if test="string-length($pText) >0">
       <xsl:value-of select=
        "substring-before(concat($pText, '&quot;'), '&quot;')"/>

       <xsl:if test="contains($pText, '&quot;')">
        <xsl:text>'</xsl:text>

        <xsl:call-template name="escapeQuote">
          <xsl:with-param name="pText" select=
          "substring-after($pText, '&quot;')"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
       </xsl:if>
      </xsl:if>

    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation made this a lot clearer. I'm still getting parsing errors though. If you want, here's a link to a live example running on my server using the unescaped characters as per the original code: [link](http://gamingfmreborn.com:8000/json2.xsl)
And here is the other file, using your code: [link](http://gamingfmreborn.com:8000/json3.xsl) Basically, it's recieving song metadata depending on what song is playing and parsing it.

Comment: @JohnBroderick Are you sure you can process XSLT _2.0_ code? I'll edit my answer in a second with another stylesheet - please try that as well.