# xslt escaping double quotes in paramters

Tags: xslt

I have some data like this (heavily edited)

```
<Chemical id="000050362" displayFormula="C17-H21-N-O4" displayName="Cocaine [BAN]">
    <NameList>
      <SystematicName>
        Cocaine
        <SourceList>
          <Source>EINECS</Source>
        </SourceList>
      </SystematicName>
      <Synonyms>
        "C" Carrie
        <SourceList>
          <Source>HSDB</Source>
          <Source>RTECS</Source>
        </SourceList>
      </Synonyms>
      <Synonyms>
      <DescriptorName>Cocaine</DescriptorName>
    </NameList>
  </Chemical>
```

I'm currently using this XSLT to extract names into a csv with a url

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" />
  <xsl:variable name="FS">
    <!-- Field seperator -->
    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:variable name="LT">
    <!-- Line terminator -->
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="//Chemical[@displayName != '' and @displayName != 'INDEX NAME NOT YET ASSIGNED']">
        <xsl:call-template name="printValues">
            <xsl:with-param name="val1" select="@id" />
            <xsl:with-param name="val2" select="@displayName" />
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="printValues">
            <xsl:with-param name="val1" select="@id" />
            <xsl:with-param name="val2" select="normalize-space(NameList/SystematicName/text())" />
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:call-template name="printValues">
            <xsl:with-param name="val1" select="@id" />
            <xsl:with-param name="val2" select="normalize-space(NameList/Synonyms/text())" />
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="printValues">
    <xsl:param name="val1" />
    <xsl:param name="val2" />

    <xsl:text>&#34;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$val2" />
    <xsl:text>&#34;</xsl:text>

    <xsl:text>&#44;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#34;</xsl:text>https://chem.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/sid/startswith/<xsl:value-of select="$val1" /><xsl:text>&#34;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#44;&#34;nlm&#34;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Example output that I'm getting

```
""C" Carrie","https://chem.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/sid/startswith/000050362","nlm"
```

What I would like

```
"\"C\" Carrie","https://chem.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/sid/startswith/000050362","nlm"
```

Now when I try and escape double quotes eg "C" Carrie it doesn't work, I suspect because I need to call a template, within a template that is called?

Could someone give me some advise?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XSLT + Replacing double quotes with escape sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370633/xslt-replacing-double-quotes-with-escape-sequence)

Comment: I might have done it wrong, but when I try and call escapeQuote I can't get it to work.. Should it be called at <xsl:with-param name="val2" select="normalize-space(NameList/SystematicName/text())" /> or within printvalues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Should it be called at `<xsl:with-param name="val2" select="normalize-space(NameList/SystematicName/text())" />` or within `printvalues`?*

The template can be called from any location. Please find below XSLT for the same. I have taken some liberty to clean up the `printValues` template and moved the `URL` and `nlm` into constants.

```
<xsl:template name="printValues">
    <xsl:param name="val1" />
    <xsl:param name="val2" />

    <!-- constants -->
    <xsl:variable name="url" select="'https://chem.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/sid/startswith/'" />
    <xsl:variable name="src" select="'nlm'" />

    <xsl:text>&#34;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:call-template name="escapeQuote">
        <xsl:with-param name="paramStr" select="$val2" />
    </xsl:call-template>
    <xsl:text>&#34;</xsl:text>

    <xsl:text>&#44;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#34;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat($url, $val1)" />
    <xsl:text>&#34;</xsl:text>

    <xsl:text>&#44;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#34;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$src" />
    <xsl:text>&#34;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="escapeQuote">
    <xsl:param name="paramStr" />

    <xsl:if test="string-length($paramStr) > 0">
        <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($paramStr, '&quot;'), '&quot;')" />
        <xsl:if test="contains($paramStr, '&quot;')">
            <xsl:text>\"</xsl:text>
            <xsl:call-template name="escapeQuote">
                <xsl:with-param name="paramStr" select="substring-after($paramStr, '&quot;')" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Output

```
"Cocaine [BAN]","https://chem.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/sid/startswith/000050362","nlm"
"Cocaine","https://chem.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/sid/startswith/000050362","nlm"
"\"C\" Carrie","https://chem.nlm.nih.gov/chemidplus/sid/startswith/000050362","nlm"
```