# XSLT XML to JSON and Escape Double Quote

Tags: json, xml, xslt, escaping, double-quotes

I'm using the following XSLT to convert XML to JSON:
https://github.com/bojanbjelic/xml2json/blob/master/xml2json.xsl

It's working great but I would really like to extend it so that any double quotes within the XML values are escaped in the JSON output:

```
<tag>This is "my" test</tag>
```

To become:

```
{
    "tag": "This is \"my\" test"
}
```

There's some good code here: [XSLT + Replacing double quotes with escape sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9370633/xslt-replacing-double-quotes-with-escape-sequence).

```
<xsl:template name="escapeQuote">
  <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>
  <xsl:if test="string-length($pText) >0">
   <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(concat($pText, '&quot;'), '&quot;')"/>
   <xsl:if test="contains($pText, '&quot;')">
    <xsl:text>\"</xsl:text>
    <xsl:call-template name="escapeQuote">
      <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, '&quot;')"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:if>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

But unfortunately I'm not experienced enough with XSLTs to integrate it with what the code I'm using from above. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which XSLT processor, which XSLT version can you use? XSLT/XPath 2 and later have a powerful `replace` function so you don't need a named template and XSLT 3 with XPath 3.1 has support for XML <--> JSON conversion which certainly does double quote escaping by default (even if the XML format used to represent JSON as XML is different from other, less robust approaches).

Comment: I’m using Apache NiFi which I think may support XSLT 3. Do you have any examples of XSLT 3 xml to JSON?

Comment: XSLT 3 support in the Java world is usually provided by using Saxon 9.8, I don't know whether Apache NiFi integrates it or allows to integrate it. As for examples, for your simple case see https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rMx/1 or https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyH9rMx/0 where the XML input is transformed into a map then serialized as JSON, of course the specs have the details about that https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-30/#json